# How to exclude configurable product sku from catalog rule

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

I am trying to exclude some list of sku's from catalog price rule, in this list simple and configurable product sku's are there. 
Successfully excluding for simple products but not working for configurable sku's.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try create one **attribute** & give value as **"1"** for Products you want to give discounts & give value as **"0"** for Products you want to give discounts.

[image]